# Correct way to statelessly update a one-to-many relationship in JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a REST interface for a datamodel that has several one-to-many and many-to-many relationships between entities. While many-to-many relationships seem easy to manage statelessly, I'm having trouble with one-to-many. Consider the following one-to-many relationship:

Employee:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Company_id")
private Company company;
```

Company:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
public Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

When a company is updated, its employee collection may have been updated as well (employees removed or added) but since the REST interface only allows updating the company as a whole, I cannot explicitly delete or add employees.

Simply replacing the collection does not work, but I found that this seems to work:

```
public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employee) {
  this.employees.clear(); // magic happens here?
  this.employees.addAll(employees);
  for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next();
    employee.setCompany(this);
  }
}
```

Is this the way it should be done, or is there a better way?

EDIT: In fact the above does not work! It appears to work at first, but then it will break with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: An entity copy was already assigned to a different entity.
```

I assume this happens because the db already contains a set of employees and if any of the "old" employees are also part of the replacement set, they collide with the ones in the database.

So what is the right way to replace the set?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by *I cannot explicitly delete or add employees* and give some examples?

Comment: Well, because it's a REST interface, I'm only getting a PUT request for Company with the employee collection, which may have changed. Fetching the persistent version of that collection and finding out which employees have been removed or added so I could explicitly call add() and remove() on them seems even more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure equals is implemented properly. As per hibernate spec: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

I had a similar problem doing a merge. Essentially I had to fetch the existing employees associated with the company. I had to merge any changes to existing employees, and then add any new employees.

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e where e.company = '" + company.getId() + "'");
    Collection<Employee> existingEmployees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    try{
        Iterables.addAll(existingEmployees, (Collection<Employee>) query.getResultList());
    }
    catch(NoResultException nre){
        //No results
    }

    for(Employee existingEmployee : existingEmployees){
        for(Employee employee : company.getEmployees()){
            if(existingEmployee.name().equals(employee.name())){
                employee.setId(existingEmployee.getId());
            }
            employee.setCompany(company);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good point. In fact I haven't implemented the equals and hashcode methods at all, yet somehow the code still works most of the time. This is one thing that bugs me - sometimes it fails consistently and sometimes I just can't reproduce the situation no matter how many times I modify the employee set.

Comment: Well that could just be the wonderment being brought on by using JPA.

Comment: so, it means, in a relationship (oneToMany in this case) you have to either play with the collection(iterate, update and merge) or remove the old collection altogether and put in a new one.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have no better choice then to replace the existing collection and simply set the new one provided by the REST response.